# Make that Javascript reads the HTML tags not as string

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a function in which I pass, mainly, a regex and an error message. What I'd like to achieve is that the browser reads the HTML code inside the Javascript code as HTML, not as a string. I've read many posts here on Stack but people seem to have exactly the opposite problem.

`oneRegex(/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/, inputValue, 'Password must contain, at least:<br> <ul><li>one number</li> <li>one capital letter</li> <li>one lower case letter</li> <li>8 carachters long</li></ul><br> i.e: passWord3', inputID);`

In this case I'd like a result like:

Password must contain, at least:

- one number
- one capital letter
- one lower case letter
- 8 carachters long

Javascript functions

```
function addErr(errMsg, inputID) {
    $('#subButton').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#err' + inputID).fadeIn(500).text(errMsg);
    $('#err' + inputID).css('background-color', '#E3BFC0');
    $('#' + inputID).css('background-color', '#E3BFC0');
}
function removeErr(inputID) {
    $('#subButton').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#err' + inputID).fadeOut(500);
    $('#' + inputID).css('background-color', 'inherit');
}

function oneRegex (regex, inputValue, errMsg, inputID) {
    if (!regex.test(inputValue)) {
        addErr(errMsg, inputID);
    }
    else {
        removeErr(inputID);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want the html interpreter to format the text use innerHTML instead of textContetn. youre not showing the code that acctually puts it in the dom so i'm not sure how you expect others to debug...

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I edited the question; I should use `.html()` instead of `.text()` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `.text` with `.html` method, like this:

```
$('#err' + inputID).fadeIn(500).html(errMsg);
```

Comment: Exactly, I tried on @Iwrestledabearonce. suggestion and it perfectly works! Thanks Kirill!